# How to Hide/Show Div when session is started with PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP. When user is logged in, or session is started,
I want to hide div class, which is button "Login".

How can I make this with PHP?

Comment: `if (userIsLoggedIn()) { hideDiv(); }`

Comment: But I need to hide only one div, not all, how can I get the id of div, that I need?

Comment: @PauliusKvasnickis can you quote your code with the mentioned div?

Comment: <button class='pris' type='submit' name='loginSubmit'>Prisijungti</button>
</form>";

Comment: echo "<div class='topnav'> <form method='POST' action='".getLogin($conn)."'>
 <input placeholder='Vardas' class='iv1' type='text' name='uid'>
 <input placeholder='Slaptažodis' class='iv2 'type='password' name='pwd'>
 <button class='pris' type='submit' name='loginSubmit'>Prisijungti</button>
</form>";

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to hide it, never output the div if the session has login information.

I.e. in your template / code that's outputting the HTML, check if the session is present (you'll have to swap `user` with whatever key you're storing the valid login under):

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])):
?>
    <div class="login"> ... </div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

.. and if you need it in a function:

```
<?php
function show_login_if_unknown() {
    if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        echo '<div class="login"> ... </div>'; // or use ?> ... <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I need that to be a function ...() { }

Comment: So wrap this code in a function, that's not rocket science.